# How canon are the Dark Tower comics?

Tags: comics, the-dark-tower

For the purposes of this question I'm classifying Dark Tower canon as the universe set out in the Stephen King *Dark Tower* books. I know Peter David is writing the comics (and other fluff), but how much input does Stephen King have?

How canon are the comics in relation to the books?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower_%28comics%29), Stephen King is credited as Creative and Executive Director of the Dark Tower comics series.  The comics series also has its own section on [the official Dark Tower web site](http://www.stephenking.com/darktower/comic/).

The thing that really makes the comics series canon though, is the fact that Robin Furth is the plotter of the series.  She's Stephen King's personal research assistant and the author of [Stephen King's The Dark Tower: A Complete Concordance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743297342).